# Searchkit - Can you search for any email that matches criteria?

Tags: searchkit

Search Criteria - in a certain group AND one of the contact's emails contains a certain domain or word.

Right now I think I can only search primary email email and I have to create or arguments for every other  type of email but billing is the only type I can get to show up.

5.69.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you search on Contacts, you get primary and billing email fields available as a convenience.

If you join to Contact Emails you get all the email fields:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think the only issue is, if a contact has two emails, lets say billing and primary, that meet same search criteria, the contact record will populate twice in search results.

Comment: Group by CID and list the emails then